# How can I prevent navigation rendering as list before the CSS and Javascript are applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, yui-pure-css

I have navigation that is built with unordered list elements in HTML. I style it with CSS ( using [PUREcss](http://purecss.io/menus/#add-dropdowns-to-menus) ). Jquery is used, as is a small JS function. These are the [implementation instructions from PUREcss](http://purecss.io/menus/#add-dropdowns-to-menus).

When the page loads, it always renders the list as normal html before rendering the navigation. What can I do to prevent the initial rendering of the list?

[image: Initial Rendering of List]

[image: Final rendering of Navigation]

Comment: You should load your CSS in the head, so it it will always been applied. To wait until JS, you can hide it in the CSS (`display: none`), and display in the JS.

Comment: I tried hiding the nav `#header-wrapper { display: none }` and then displaying it on page load `$(document).ready(function() { $("#header-wrapper").show(); });` ... It does initially hide the nav, and then display it with JS, but it doesn't solve the list rendering issue.

Comment: Make sure `$("#header-wrapper").show();` is after the the menu JavaScript loads

Comment: It's the last JS function called before </head>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Pure's example code](http://purecss.io/menus/), add the `show()` call there...

```
<script>
YUI({
    classNamePrefix: 'pure'
}).use('gallery-sm-menu', function (Y) {

    var horizontalMenu = new Y.Menu({
        container         : '#demo-horizontal-menu',
        sourceNode        : '#std-menu-items',
        orientation       : 'horizontal',
        hideOnOutsideClick: false,
        hideOnClick       : false
    });

    horizontalMenu.render();
    horizontalMenu.show();

    $("#header-wrapper").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works, whereas, showing it later with a separate JS call that occurs after this one didn't. Any thoughts on the difference?

Comment: Also ... is hiding then showing the nav with javascript going to be a problem for certain users / browsers? I assume not, simply because the nav required javascript anyway.

Comment: This must fire after jQuery's `$(document).ready()`. It's odd to me that Pure doesn't apply css to the menu *before* JavaScript loads it.

Answer (score 2):

Use document ready for all of your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //all js
}
```

And put your css in your head, so everything renders before the DOM elements are loaded:

```
<head>
<style></style>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--All your html-->
</body>
```

Comment: I've done all of this ... and just verified it. All CSS and Javascript load in <head>. All Javascript <script>'s are wrapped in "document ready." Other ideas?